# use config when the widget is defined in a class, tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
class lab3l(Label):
    def __init__(self):
        super(lab3l, self).__init__()
        self=Label(text="label",fg="red")
        self.pack()
l=lab3l()
button=Button(text="button",command=lambda:(l.config(fg="blue")))
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I don't get any error but the code does not work

Comment: When you use `super().__init__()` you create 1 label and then when you use `self = Label(...)`, you create another label. Move the `text="label"` and the `fg="red"` inside the `super().__init__()` and remove the `self=Label(text="label",fg="red")`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment:

- You are inheriting from `Label` but create another `Label`. There is no reason to do that.
- Also your `lab3l` class seems a bit useless, it's just a `tkinter.Label` but with pre-set `text` and `fg`.

Your code fixed:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

class lab3l(Label):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, text="label", fg="red")

l = lab3l(root)
l.pack()
button = Button(text="button", command=lambda: l.config(fg="blue"))
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Overall there are a few things in your code that will be considered bad practise like:

- not passing in a `master` argument when creating the label
- using `from tkinter import *`

Answer (score -1):

In the end, you decide. But I personally think that you drive better with it, if you have everything in a class. So possibly do without this type of combination. Because the way it is, that has led to confusion

```
root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
class lab3l(Label):
    def __init__(self):
        super(lab3l, self).__init__()
        self.lbl = Label(text="label", fg= "red")
        self.lbl.pack()
    def con_any(self):
        self.lbl.config(fg="blue")
l=lab3l()
button=Button(text="button",command=l.con_any)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

or

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
class lab3l(Label):
    def __init__(self):
        super(lab3l, self).__init__()
        self.lbl = Label(text="label", fg= "red")
        self.lbl.pack()

l=lab3l()
button=Button(text="button",command=lambda : l.lbl.config(fg="green")) # make a refernece to your class
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code is very bad. You inherit from `Label` and create a `Label` widget but never call `.pack` on it. Instead you create another `Label`???

Comment: i just copied this code from this guy and paste a solution. I answered his question, the question wasnt about inherent. I'm not here (in your own words) to make a complete new app. and if you have a better solution, then post it. i think you have more exp than myself. so let end this here, and help this guy

Comment: Look at my answer. It solves the problem I pointed out, while solving OP's problem. Also the point of this website is to help people. If something will help OP, why not include it in your answer?

Comment: yes but it doesn't come clear to me. have you waiting for a comment from another user? your first post was an hour ago. so why no answer? i' m not here for bashing anyone, i want to learn usefull stuff

Comment: I am here to learn too. Also if I can fit the whole answer in a few sentences, I find it pointless to write an answer when I can write a comment. Again my point is to help other people and to learn new things. I wrote the answer to show you how you could have solved OP's problem while removing the problem I pointed out. It also speeds up the code and takes up less space.

Comment: OK. maybe i missed that. because i find it more interesting to be presented with a solution than to post it in these subtitles. There are a lot of bright minds here who, in my opinion, invest too much text in these subtitles. The guy who asked the question would be better helped if you presented this solution right away. And I actually like your solution better than mine.

Comment: The problem with writing solutions is that they have to be formal and longer. Also I make it my point to address at least some of the bad practices/misconceptions. That is why I write comments, but you are right, if a comment is too long people aren't going to read it. Also if you remove the inheritance from your answer, it will be a better answer than mine.